# Rest Assured - Error 404 when authenticating using localhost

Tags: rest-assured

I'm testing an API using localhost, in the manual tests it went well using Postman, as follows in the screenshot:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVusX.png)

As the screenshot shows, it's necessary to send the username and password in the request body, then the API returns the Authentication key in the response header, and the Status 200 OK.

But when I tried to automate the test to see if I could retrieve the key from the header response, the test failed with statusCode 404, and I can't even proceed to see if it gets the authorization in the header. Is there something I'm missing when automating this kind of request?

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class reusableMethods {

    public static String getSessionKey() {

        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:3000";
        Response res =
                given().log().all().
                        header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                        body("{\n" +
                                "  \"email\": \"admin@test.com.br\",\n" +
                                "  \"password\": \"passw0rd\"\n" +
                                "}").
                        when().
                            post("/api/cms/v1/auth/login").
                        then().assertThat().
                            statusCode(200).
                            extract().response();

        String headerValue = res.header("Authorization");
        System.out.println(headerValue);
        return headerValue;

    }
```

When I run the test, I always get the same error, as follows along with the log:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:3000/api/cms/v1/auth
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
    "email": "admin@test.com.br",
    "password": "passw0rd"
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <404>.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use auth() method to pass Authentication.
It has multiple options, you need to see which one suits your authenication.

If your are using OAuth token, then it will be like:

```
 Response res =  given()
                .auth().oauth2("Your token")
                .log().all().
                header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                body("{\n" + "  \"email\": \"admin@test.com.br\",\n" +"  \"password\": \"passw0rd\"\n" +"}").
                when().
                    post("/api/cms/v1/auth/login").
                then().
                    assertThat().
                        statusCode(200).extract().response();
```